# Running a PHP file using AJAX async but still it takes time when i reload the page just after calling it through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, php-curl

I am running a PHP file using AJAX async but still it takes time when i reload the page just after calling it through ajax

What i guess is there is an SELECT query then an curl request and an INSERT query in a loop and i guess this is running synchronous

Like when i call this php file through AJAX and then when i try to open another page that page won't open till this task gets completed

My PHP file -

```
$smmapi = new SMMApi();
$web_id = WEBSITE_ID;

            $orders = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders INNER JOIN service_api ON service_api.id=orders.order_api WHERE orders.website_id=:web_id ");
            $orders-> execute(array("web_id"=>WEBSITE_ID ));
            $orders = $orders->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            foreach($orders as $order){
                $result =  $smmapi->action(array('key' =>$order['api_key'],'action' =>'refill','order' =>$order['api_orderid']),$order['api_url']);
                $result = json_decode( json_encode($result), true);
              
                if(!empty($result['error'])){
                    $error = $error+1;
                }else{
              
                     if(!empty($result['refill'])){
                        $conn->beginTransaction();
                        $insert= $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO refill SET refill_order_id=:order_id, refill_api_order_id=:api_order_id, refill_client_id=:client_id, refill_service_id=:service_id, refill_mode=:mode, refill_status=:status, last_updated=:updated, refill_created=:created, website_id=:web_id ");
                        $insert= $insert->execute(array("order_id"=>$order["order_id"],"api_order_id"=>$result['refill'],"client_id"=>$order['client_id'],"service_id"=>$order['service_id'],"mode"=>"auto","status"=>"pending","updated"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),"created"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),"web_id"=>WEBSITE_ID ));
                        if( $insert ){
                          $conn->commit();
                          $success = $success+1;
                        }else{
                          $conn->rollback();
                          $error = $error+1;
                        }
                      }else{
                          $error = $error+1;
                      }
                }
            }
            if($orders){
                $result = "<strong>Command executed successfully</strong> <br> <strong>Failed refills:</strong> $error <br> <strong>Successful refills:</strong> $success";    
            }else{
                $result = "<strong>Command executed successfully</strong> <br> <strong>No refillable orders found</strong>";
            }    
            $_SESSION["data"]["result_refills"]   = $result;
?>
```

This is my SMMApi() class which is sending the curl request -

```
<?php

class SMMApi{

  public $api_url = '';
  public $apiKEY = '';

  public function action($data,$api){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $api);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST , true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch) != 0 && empty($result)) {
      $result = false;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result);

  }

}
```

And this is how i am calling it on click of a button -

```
 $(".refill_all").click(function(){
        
        var site_url  = $('head base').attr('href');

        $.LoadingOverlay("show");
       
        var orders = {
          "url": site_url+"admin/orders/multi-action?bulkStatus=orders_refill",
          "method": "GET",
          "timeout": 0,
        };
        
        $.ajax(orders).done(function (response) {
            $("#bulk_refill_ajax").hide();
            $("#bulk_refill_ajax_result").show();
            $("#bulk_refill_ajax_result").html(response.content);
        });
        
        $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
        $("#bulk_refill_ajax").show();
  });
```

Please help me to run that php file in background and all of my website runs normally till that code runs in background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `beginnTransaction` and `commit` in the loop - why?  `prepare` also, you only need to call it once...

Comment: Where are you running this code? Your local machine? Some cheap/free Internet hosting?

Comment: Are you using PHP sessions in both scripts? Then the session file write lock might be the issue.

Comment: The problem is most likely caused by your hosting provider only allowing 1 active connection to the server per client. This means that while the AJAX request is occurring, no other requests can be made, hence it appears that the async operation is actually synchronous. I'd suggest checking your hosting plan, and finding a better one.

Comment: @ADyson i am using an AWS instance and installed centos and then CPANEL on it if there is any tweak i need to make then tell me

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am using cpanel on an AWS instance i have a full control on the server please tell me how can i enable multiple connections